# Selecting Field Multiple Times using OR

Tags: sql

I want to write a query similar to this:

```
Select * from table where EMPLID = 1 OR EMPLID = 2 OR EMPLID = 3 OR EMPLID = 4;
```

Is there any easy way to break this down or do I have to use OR for each case?

Comment: do you really have to -1 me?  I didn't know this was a duplicate otherwise I wouldn't ask it

Comment: Take a look at the [How to Ask Guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for some guidance, but when a question has a very accessible answer it will get downvoted.

Comment: The question mention by @Malkus is not a duplicate - however there will be other duplicates as a basic question - you need the IN clause

Answer (score 5):

Use the `IN` syntax:

```
SELECT ..
...
WHERE EMPLID IN (1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: @JoeEngle Don't do that please. People will upvote your question based on its own merits.

Comment: accept downvotes as a fact of life here. I'm not going to upvote just to cancel out someone else's. Your question is a dupe. It just happened to be faster for me to type out the answer than it was to find/link the dupe.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer.  It is correct but I will not approve it per your decision